# WP All Import HTTP Authentication

Tags: import, feed, http-authentication

I'm using WP All Import to import an XML file. Their website states password protected files may be accessed via Basic HTTP Authentication,  appending user credentials to the requested URL as such http://username:password@link-to-file. When attempted, the following error is returned:

> RETS ReplyCode="20036" ReplyText="Missing User-Agent request header field."

The error is expected as the URL does not include headers required for authentication. From what I've researched, this method of passing credentials via the URL has been deprecated as it is unsecure. Do I need to create a function to pass the credentials to the server? I take it it's not quite as simple as "Basic HTTP Authentication."

I've contacted WP Import and thought I'd tap Stack while waiting. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Update. Received a response from Soflyy Wp All Import. They say I may be able pass credentials in headers using http_api_curl action: 
`add_action( 'http_api_curl', 'my_setopt_http_api_curl', 10, 3 );
function my_setopt_http_api_curl( $handle, $r, $url ) {
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36" );
}`

Comment: Update from WP All Import
Unfortunately, this is going to be a bit complicated. Write a small plugin for your site that does the following:

• Loads the RETS PHP library that they sent you.
• Defines a "download" PHP function that uses the RETS library to connect to your RETS feed, downloads the data, then saves it in a file and returns that file location.

Then, you can use the download function in the import via the "Download from URL" option. 

Here's an example of how to write a download function for WP All Import: https://gist.github.com/trey8611/6fbf6d36b5b86068d86253ccf934eb55.